# F#: RProvider fails to load stats.dll for ggplot2

Tags: r, f#, visual-studio-2017

I am getting an error when trying to use RProvider for F# in Visual Studio 2017.

I discovered the problem while trying to load the package ggplot2:

```
module ggplot2Program

open System
open RProvider
open RProvider.ggplot2
```

When I attempt this and then try to use the ggplot2 library under
`RProvider.ggplot2.R`

I simply obtain this error message in the log file for RProvider:

> [06/02/2018 22:05:16] [Pid:13556, Tid:5, Apid:1] Adding work item to queue
>
> [06/02/2018 22:05:16] [Pid:13556, Tid:1, Apid:1] server event loop: got work item
>
> [06/02/2018 22:05:16] [Pid:13556, Tid:1, Apid:1] eval(require(ggplot2))
>
> [06/02/2018 22:05:16] [Pid:13556, Tid:1, Apid:1] Output: Loading required > package: ggplot2
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2' in inDL(x, > as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
>
> unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
>
> LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

I have tried reinstalling R and swapping the `stats.dll` in the `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library/stats/libs/x64/` and `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\library\stats\libs\i386` directories but this simply results in a "not a valid Win32 application" error in the log.

What could be the problem? Is RProvider detecting Visual Studio as a x64 process or is it something else?

Comment: I thought R defaults to installed both `i386` and `x64` architectures, so it should still be available regardless if VS is identifying as a 32- or 64-bit process. I don't think it'll be the culprit, but I've found many issues with R on windows when there is a space somewhere in the installed path. Because of that, I have always installed within `c:\R\R-3.4.3` and `c:\Rtools\` ... yes it clutters the local drive and permissions might be a problem, but if you have the ability to find some non-network non-spaced path for installation, that might change things. (I'm stretching, sorry.)

Comment: Installing to C:\R-3.4.3\ did not work. I got the same error as before. However, it seems that this is specific to some update of R, since I installed R-3.3.1 and there were no problems - I was able to install ggplot2 as well and use its library functions! It seems to be due to a change in R-3.4?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be due to the presence of etc\Renvirons.site file in the v3.4.3 release of R.

I had a similar issue and deleting the etc\Renviron.site file and restarting VS 2013 resolved it.

See the following github issue: https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet/issues/62